# Effect of Gate-Drain Capacitance on Input Impedance of CS Amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I am studying MOSFET amplifiers and came along the following interesting statement:

The gate-drain capacitance of the MOSFET in a CS amplifier decreases the input impedance of the amplifier.

I spent quite a lot of time to verify this which was unsuccessful until now.
Can someone please give me some insight?

Comment: Please show some sign of research on your own. What other details are in that statement?

Comment: My first intuition would be to consider a input resistance Rin in a small-signal model, to which the gate-drain capacitance Cgd is placed in series. The total impedance of the two should than be lower than Re(Z) but numerical analysis shows the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a gate-drain capacitance will add to the total capacitance seen at the gate. Including the Miller-effect, you would get something along the lines of

$$C_{in} = C_{gs} + (1-A)C_{gd}$$

The input impedance decreases because of it:

$$Z_{in} = \frac{1}{C_{in}s} = \frac{1}{(C_{gs} + (1-A)C_{gd})s}$$

It means that you will need *more* current to change the input voltage for all frequencies.

Note that it does *not* decrease the input *resistance* which can be considered the impedance at DC (\$s\to 0^+\$ then \$Z_{in}\to +\infty\$), which is irrelevant for MOS transistors as the gate is isolated from the channel.

Comment: Mike657, please take into account that for a common source stage the gain A in Sven`s answer is negative!